# Responsive 9:16 HTML video element on iOS

Tags: html, css, flexbox, html5-video

I want to make a 9:16 video responsive with dynamic content below. I want the full container to take up the height of the screen, and then the video to scale based on the height / # of the items below it. How can I make this happen?

I've tried doing this with flexbox, but on iOS safari, the video takes up the full width of the container which means it doesn't respect the height of the container and pushes the items below the fold.

```
    <div
      className="flex flex-col"
      style={{
        height: window.innerHeight,
      }}
    >
      <div className="flex-1 bg-gray-500">
        <video
          src="https://assets.mixkit.co/videos/preview/mixkit-tree-with-yellow-flowers-1173-large.mp4"
          autoPlay
          playsInline
        ></video>
      </div>
      <div>foo</div>
      <div>bar</div>
      <div>baz</div>
    </div>
```

This is in JSX, but I couldn't get it to work in vanilla HTML either.

Answer (score 0):

I had more success using grid rather than flex - defining the column to have 4 rows, all being auto except the first one.

The video is placed absolutely with height of 100%.

This snippet is a pure HTML/CSS version (with a bit of JS to set the height to window.innerHeight as in the question's code).

Tested on Safari IOS 15 on iPad.

```js
const container = document.querySelector('.container');
container.style.height = window.innerHeight + 'px';
```

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr auto auto auto;
}

.video {
  background: gray;
  position: relative;
}

video {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="video">
    <div class="sub">
      <video src="https://assets.mixkit.co/videos/preview/mixkit-tree-with-yellow-flowers-1173-large.mp4" autoplay playsinline></video></div>
  </div>
  <div>foo</div>
  <div>bar</div>
  <div>baz</div>
</div>
```